# Extracting multiple lines of data from single cell to multiple cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a mailing list that's setup in Excel. There is only one column and each cell has a full mailing address. I need each line of data from each cell extrapolated to the appropriate columns in order to sort the address correctly.

For example:

```
John Smith
123 Main St.
New York, NY 00000
```

Extrapolated to this ( "|" denotes a new cell)

```
John Smith | 123 Main St. | New York | NY | 00000
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is there a specific character used to wrap the address lines that can be used to parse the address?

Comment: "*Each cell has an entire address list.*" --> What's an "address list"?

Comment: If line break (ALT Enter) was used to split the text in to multiple lines, you can simply use ALT 0010 (Alt key followed by 0010) as 'Other' delimiter character in Text To Columns option dialog box and split it along the line break to multiple columns. The ALT 0010 may not be visible in the delimiter text box but its end result shall be as expected.

Comment: @fixer1234 Unfortunately, no. The answer below shows what my address list looks like (Column A).

Comment: @techraf Edited.

Comment: The wrapping isn't at a position where it's based on a space closest to the cell margin, so there is a hidden character, like Tab, LF, CR, or something similar that Excel is wrapping on.  Gary's Student's answer assumes it is LF (Chr(10)).  You can determine what it is.  In your John Smith example, it is likely the 11th character, although there could be one or more spaces before it, so you might need to try successive positions).  If the John Smith address is in cell A1, use this formula: =CODE(MID(A1,11,1)), which will return the ASCII code for the hidden 11th character.

Comment: @techraf After using the formula, I discovered the hidden character is LF.

Comment: @techraf Success! I found the appropriate functions in Google Sheets to split strings using LF as the delimiter. Could you comment the corresponding function for Excel? I believe it's the LEFT function.

Comment: There is no SPLIT worksheet function in Excel, but it does exist in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you wish to process and run this short macro:

```
Sub ReOrganizer()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(r.Text, Chr(10))
        r.Offset(0, 1) = ary(0)
        r.Offset(0, 2) = ary(1)
        bry = Split(ary(2), ", ")
        r.Offset(0, 3) = bry(0)
        cry = Split(bry(1), " ")
        r.Offset(0, 4) = cry(0)
        r.Offset(0, 5) = "'" & cry(1)
    Next r
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ended up using a SPLIT function on Google sheets using chr(10) as the delimiter. I will refer to this when I want to get into macros!